# Fetch customizer image and output as an inline css style background image

Tags: theme-customizer, images, custom-background, get-theme-mod

So I have a feeling this is quite simple, but Im a bone head since I'm still learning PHP as I hack away at themes via my own child-theming...

In short, I've built a customizer section in my `functions.php` where I can add my own background image that I would then like to fetch in my `search.php` template and output as a inline `background-image` style. As far as I can tell, Im just not formatting my php correctly but I do seem to be effectively calling the url into the page when it loads, just nothing happens yet.

Maybe someone can enlighten me on where Im screwing this up hopefully.

Example:

```
<header class="page-header search-header" style="background-image: url('
            <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'hbps_searchresults_bg_img' ) > 0 ) { 
                echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_theme_mod( 'hbps_searchresults_bg_img' ), 'full' ); } ?> ');">
```

Thank you for your time.

Best,
Shaun

Comment: It could be as simple as a space character. At the end of your code try `} ?>');">` (delete the space between closing of PHP and the single quote at the end of the URL).

Comment: Geez, I cant believe it was even simpler than I anticipated, lol. THANK YOU!